# How can I change a path according to the vmImage in a matrix?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I create a pipeline which runs three jobs: 1x Windows, 1x MacOS, 1x Linux.
The yaml file looks like this:

```
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "PowerShell_Tests"
  - job: PowerShell_Tests
    strategy:
      matrix:
        linux:
          imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
        windows:
          imageName: 'windows-latest'
        mac:
          imageName: 'macos-latest'
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    pool:
      vmImage: $(imageName)

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s\src\bin\Debug\net6.0\publish\package.dll'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

The `targetPath` in the *PublishPipelineArtifact@1* task works fine for Windows but fails for MacOS and Linux.

Is it possible to provide path options according to the vmImage?

Comment: Just flip the `\ ` to `/` will probably solve the issue.

Comment: @jessehouwing, thanks... problem is then though that the Windows job fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define path individually for each confoguration

```
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "PowerShell_Tests"
  - job: PowerShell_Tests
    strategy:
      matrix:
        linux:
          imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
          artifactPath: '/s/src/bin/Debug/net6.0/publish/package.dll'
        windows:
          imageName: 'windows-latest'
          artifactPath: '\s\src\bin\Debug\net6.0\publish\package.dll'
        mac:
          imageName: 'macos-latest'
          artifactPath: '/s/src/bin/Debug/net6.0/publish/package.dll'
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    pool:
      vmImage: $(imageName)

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)$(artifactPath)'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Comment: Works like an absolute charm. Thank you very much!